# Need equivalent code in c# from javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, vb.net

Need equivalent code in C# or vb.net for this javascript code.

```
    var rules = {
    a: 'അ',
    a2: 'ആ',
    a3: 'എ',
    aa: 'ആ',
    A2: 'ആ',
    A3: 'എ',
    i: 'ഇ',
    i2: 'ഈ',
    i3: 'ഐ'
    };
var pattern = rules["a"];
```

Comment: You mean [you need to make an array in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: you cant give string to array as index. so i think dictionary is the best choice. @hoss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C# Use [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
        Dictionary<string, char> rules = new Dictionary<string, char>
        {
            {a, 'അ'},
            {a2, 'ആ'},
            {a3, 'എ'},
            {aa, 'ആ'},
            {A2, 'ആ'},
            {A3, 'എ'},
            {i, 'ഇ'},
            {i2, 'ഈ'},
            {i3, 'ഐ'}
        };

        var pattern = rules["a"];
```

I assumed that type of `a`,`a2`,`a3`,... is `string` as you didnt mentioned what are the types.

What you have is called Associative arrays. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21899818/javascript-associative-arrays).

The closest Alternative in C# is [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Where you can give object as key and Get value.

Comment: Yes a,a2,a3,.. are strings.

Comment: so this is what you need. @binuj

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more explicit with what you are trying to do exactly, but this would compile under certain circumstances:

```
class Chars
{
    public char a;
    public char a2;
    public char a3;
    public char aa;
    public char A2;
    public char A3;
    public char i;
    public char i2;
    public char i3;
}

Chars rules = new Chars {
a= 'അ',
a2= 'ആ',
a3= 'എ',
aa= 'ആ',
A2= 'ആ',
A3= 'എ',
i= 'ഇ',
i2= 'ഈ',
i3= 'ഐ'
};

char pattern = rules.a;
```

Comment: its not class. in JavaScript. Its called [associative array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21899818/javascript-associative-arrays)

Comment: thats why you have to be more detailed with what you are trying to do... theres 20 different ways you can reformat that for C#